# Azure's DNS update with CLI from JSON?

Tags: azure, dns, automation, continuous-integration

Currently, we have a simple solution for AWS's Route53 to update zones/records.

It looks like:

```
...
for f in $FILES; do
  echo "[$me] Processing $f file..."
  echo "[$me] Upadating Route53 for zone *** with changes from $f"
  aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id *** --change-batch file://$f
done
...
```

Then, each JSON contains data like:

```
{
  "Comment":"Records related to the",
  "Changes":[
   {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "www.***.io"
          }
        ],
        "Type": "CNAME",
        "Name": "www.***",
        "TTL": 300
      }
  }
  ]
}
```

The new project, located on Azure, also have a bunch of zones and I'd like to have similar ability. I.e. - store JSONs with zones in Git and update entries on the Azure DNS with CI server build (kind of **IaC**)

After a lot of googling for Azure's CLI, API, Chef etc methods - there is still no even understanding - is it possible for Azure?

P.S. During posting this Q I found a `network dns zone export [options] <resource-group> <name> <file-name>` in Azure's CLI help, which looks like what I'm looking for. Nevertheless - any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have an easy tool to add modifications to your Azure via CLI, `azure network dns import/export` is actually the command you need.

You can export existing items via `export` command and add corrections you need in this file.

After that you can call `import` command to update DNS parameters.

If you'll use `import <resource-group> <name>` command for dns name which does not exist in the resource group, it will be created for you.

If the zone already exists, the imported record sets will be merged with existing record sets.

To **overwrite** the existing record sets, use the `--force` option. Further details on how record sets are merged given by [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-import-export/). This option would update your DNS records.